# "open with" and Spotlight cluttered with different versions of files/apps

Tags: macos, spotlight, indexing

The app versions are not even in my Applications directory anymore. Is there something wrong or can I edit settings for that somewhere? It seems as if my backup drive is indexed as well. How to avoid that?

See screenshots:

[image: imgur]

[image: imgur]

Answer (score 1):

To disable indexing of the back up drive

Open Spotlight in System preferences

click on Privacy Tab,

drag the drive in question in to here

or use the <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solved the Spotlight issue. The "open with" issue unfortunately persists.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X 10.5 and later:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregisterkill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before. The command seemed to be executed, but the problem persists.